# Pivot my sql rows into columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have below structure.
|id|value|

|a|v1|

|b|v2|

|c|v3|

|d|v4|

Output needed.

|a|  b| c|d|

|v1|v2|v3|v4|

I tried many, but could get success

```
select case  when t1.id  = 'a' then t1.value end as a ,
         case    when t1.id  = 'b' then t1.value end as b ,
          case   when t1.id  = 'c' then t1.value end as b ,
          case   when t1.id  = 'd' then t1.value end as d 


           from
t1
```

please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use aggregate function for your required result set

```
select max(case  when t1.id  = 'a' then t1.value end) as a ,
       max(case  when t1.id  = 'b' then t1.value end) as b ,
       max(case  when t1.id  = 'c' then t1.value end) as b ,
       max(case  when t1.id  = 'd' then t1.value end) as d 
from t1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b6dfa/3)

> Note using aggregate function without group by will consider whole table as a single group